# How to dynamically input the shape to a placeholder

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, placeholder

I have a function which will retrieve `batch of sentences`, create a `bag of words` from the words in the sentences, creates `character id matrix` from the words in the bag of words.

```
char_id_batch, word_id_batch, pos_id_batch = temp.retrieve_batch_sent(start, batch_size_counter)
```

I have three placeholders:

1. char_id: The shape of char_id is `[length of bag of words, maximum length of word in bag of words]` from each `batch of sentences`.
2. word_id: The shape of word_id is `[batch of sentences, maximum length of sentence in batch of sentences]` from each `batch of sentences`.
3. output: The shape of `y` is the same as word_id.

I do not know the shape before calling the `retrieve` function. I can return the shapes using the `retrieve` function, but I do not know how to give them as input to the `char_id`, `word_id` and `y`. I was hoping the shapes would be inferred from `feed_dict`, but they aren't.

Partial code:

```
char_id = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, None])
word_id = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, None])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, None])

with tf.name_scope("CharacterLayer"):
    with tf.variable_scope("CharacterLayer"):
        char_embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[char_codes, char_embed_size]))
        char_lookup = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(char_embeddings, char_id)
        char_train = tf.unstack(value=char_lookup, axis=1)
        char_lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(word_embed_size, forget_bias=1)
        output_words, _ = rnn.static_rnn(cell=char_lstm_cell, inputs=char_train, dtype=tf.float32)

for i in range(1, itr):
        char_id_batch, word_id_batch, pos_id_batch = temp.retrieve_batch_sent(start, batch_size_counter)
        start = batch_size_counter
        batch_size_counter = batch_size + batch_size_counter
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={char_id: char_id_batch, word_id: word_id_batch, y: pos_id_batch})
```

I know that `tf.unstack` does not work if the argument is unspecified and non-inferrable. That is why I get the error: `ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape (?, ?, 10)`.

Is there is a way to feed the `shapes` or do I have to manually in enter the `shapes`, in the `placeholders`?

Comment: Feed the shape as another placeholder and resize before calling tf.unstack.

Comment: @RyanJay: I did but I get the error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'`, 

this is what I did: 

`word_max_len = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)`
`sent_max_len = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)`
`char_id = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, word_max_len])`
`word_id = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, sent_max_len])`
`y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, sent_max_len])`

Comment: `char_id_batch, word_id_batch, pos_id_batch, word_max_len_batch, sent_max_len_batch = Reader.retrieve_batch_sent(start, batch_size_counter)`
`feed_dict = {char_id: char_id_batch, word_id: word_id_batch, y: pos_id_batch}`
`sess.run(tf.shape(word_max_len), feed_dict = {word_max_len: word_max_len_batch)`
`sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)`

Comment: I tried to directly feed without using `sess.run(tf.shape(word_max_len), feed_dict = {word_max_len: word_max_len_batch)`, but in `sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)`, I still get the same error.